# `with open...` doesn't work in scheduled task on Windows

Tags: python, windows, scheduled-tasks

I work with Python on Linux, but I'm forced to schedule a task on Windows. I was having a hard time automating my scripts here. The best alternative for cron I have found is this command

`schtasks /Create /SC MINUTE /TN TestTask_Python /TR "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\python.exe C:\Users\user_name\Desktop\test.py"`

It runs the script every minute and it kind of works. [Documentation.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb736357(v=vs.85).aspx)

Case 1. Running from IDE. (PyCharm/Idle) Script works.
Case 2. Running from cmd. `> python test.py` Script works.
Case 3. Runs scheduled task. The script works partially.

Case3 prints `not added` and it's done, while Case1 and Case2 prints `not added`, adds `datetime` to `test_time.txt` and prints `added`.

```
import time
import datetime
import json
from datetime import date

if __name__ == "__main__":

    now = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(time.time()).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

    print('not added')
    time.sleep(2)
    with open('test_time.txt', 'a+') as pf:
        pf.write('{0} \n'.format(now))
        print('added')
        time.sleep(1)
    time.sleep(1)
```

I double checked my enviro variables and python PATH matches the path I put in the schtasks cmd.

Am I missing something? Why `with open...` doesn't work in this case?

Comment: Probably you should use full path to your file

Comment: Yes, you're missing something. Most likely the working directory or working drive isn't what you expect, and it tried to create test_time.txt somewhere else. Try an absolute pathname or os.chdir first.

Comment: You might be getting an exception with it not being able to create the file. As suggested, use a full path to a location which you definitely have write permission. As a test you could try and run the process as an Administrator and see where on Windows the file turns up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The process has a different working directory when run as a windows task.

Use an **absolute path** in your call to `open()`.